# Find the row which contain specific date. Error 91

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to find the row which contain the date same as my other file. But it has the error 91  on the line defining the row number. Anyone can help me to tackle this prob? The 'mth' was successfully found.

```vb
Sub abc()

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim PCFilePath As String
    Dim PCFile As String
    Dim RSFilePath As String
    Dim RSFile As String
    Dim mth As Date
    Dim row_mth As Long
    Dim Date1 As Date
    Dim Date2 As Date

    PCFilePath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
    PCFile = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")
    RSFilePath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8")
    RSFile = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9")
    mth = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")

    Workbooks.Open (PCFilePath & PCFile), UpdateLinks:=0
    Set x = Workbooks.Open(PCFilePath & PCFile)

    Workbooks.Open (RSFilePath & RSFile), UpdateLinks:=0
    Set y = Workbooks.Open(RSFilePath & RSFile)

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook

    row_mth = y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Find(What:=mth, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
```

Comment: That error is most likely because this `y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Find(What:=mth, LookIn:=xlValues).Row` does not actually find your date. Your second date might not be in the same format as the first one, hence the fail...

Answer (score 1):

Dates can be tricky when using `Range.Find`  It can be format dependent, and also the Date data type in VBA is not the same as on the worksheet.  One is stored as a Double, the other as a VBA Date data type.

Instead try:

```
Dim mth as Double
```

or

```
.Find(What:=CDbl(mth), ...
```

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Tks for catching that.